# Error while using print command in python 3.3.2

Tags: python, random, printing, python-3.3

```
import random
print((((random.randrange(1,12)//(((random.randrange(1,4)))))))+10)
print((((random.randrange(1,12)//(((random.randrange(1,4)))))))+10)
```

This is my code so far and it successfully generates two random numbers between the desired integers , now i need it to print in the format of,

```
Strength = 12
Stamina = 14
```

I tried like this:

```
import random
print ' strength = '((((random.randrange(1,12)//(((random.randrange(1,4)))))))+10)
print 'stamina ='((((random.randrange(1,12)//(((random.randrange(1,4)))))))+10)
```

But this returns an error for a reason unknown to me, I have been stuck on this for hours and I would really appreciate it if someone would help me with this problem, THANKS :)

Comment: Why do you have so many parentheses? Two pairs of parentheses around an expression won't do any more than one pair, and even one pair is usually unnecessary.

Comment: please please reduce your parentheses. although that is exactly why I clicked on the question. caught my eye. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print` is a function in python3, use `()` to wrap your contents and `,` to separate them. And you don't need soooo many extra `()`s:

```
In [40]: print('stamina =', random.randrange(1,12)//random.randrange(1,4)+10)
#stamina = 14
```

Answer (score 0):

import speech_recognition as  sr
import pyttsx3

```
listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say('Iam your alexa')
engine.say('what can i do for you')
engine.runAndWait()
```

try:

```
with sr.Microphone() as source:
print('listening...')
voice = listener.listen(source)
command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
command = command.lower()
if 'alexa' in command:
 print(command)
```

except:
pass

Comment: print('listening...') command not working iam using python 2020 3.3 any error so please slove

Comment: python is sensitive to indentation and whitespace. Try formatting your code properly.